# How to pass int via eventListener in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, json

I generate a list of Magic cards from a Json file.

```
for (i in set.cards) {
        leftCardElement = document.createElement("p");
        leftCardElement.innerHTML = set.cards[i].points + "&nbsp;" + set.cards[i].name + "&nbsp";
        leftCardElement.addEventListener("click", leftCardClicked);
}

 function leftCardClicked(event) {// access card.cost and other things }
```

The problem is that when the `leftCardElementClicked()` method is called I'd like to be able to have access to the `set.cards[i]` object. The `this` object seems to refer to the element that I clicked on inside of `leftCardElementClicked()`. Is there some way that I can pass the index `i` to the event handler so I can get my card object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Same like @AlejandroC but without the dependency on the `i` (this `i` will change on each iteration) , 
therefore I clone it before passing, using with [Object.assign()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign)

In your for loop do:

```
leftCardElement.addEventListener("click", leftCardClicked.bind(this, Object.assign({},set.cards[i]));
```

then your function should be:

```
function leftCardClicked(card, event) { ... }
```

Answer (score 0):

In your for loop do:

```
leftCardElement.addEventListener("click", leftCardClicked.bind(this, set.cards[i]);
```

then your function should be:

```
function leftCardClicked(card, event) { ... }
```

Answer (score -1):

Instead of attaching leftCardClicked directly as your event handler, instead use an anonymous function:

```
leftCardElement.addEventListener("click", function(evt) {
  leftCardClicked(evt,i);
});
```

where i is your loop index. This creates a closure that passes that value of i to that instance of the click handler.